# Weird error using Smart Contracts with @usedapp and @ethersproject/contracts

Tags: typescript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, brownie

Hello there I'm trying to use a contract made on solidity and deployed with brownie on my front end using React and typescript. also using the framework usedapp, as the documentation [here](https://usedapp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html?highlight=useContractFunction#executing-contract-function) says in order to interact with a contract function I should create a new contract, providing the address and the ABI. Here is my code:

```js
import {useContractFunction, useEthers} from '@usedapp/core'
import TokenFarm from "../chain-info/contracts/TokenFarm.json"
import ERC20 from "../chain-info/contracts/MockERC20.json"
import networkMapping from "../chain-info/deployments/map.json"
import {constants, utils} from "ethers"
import {Contract} from '@ethersproject/contracts'

export const useStakeTokens = (tokenAddress: string) => {
    // chainId 
    const {chainId} = useEthers()
    // abi
    const {abi} = TokenFarm
    // address
    // const dappTokenAddress = chainId ? networkMapping[String(chainId)]["DappToken"][0] : constants.AddressZero
    const tokenFarmAddress = chainId ? networkMapping[String(chainId)]["TokenFarm"][0] : constants.AddressZero
    // approve
    const tokenFarmInterface = new utils.Interface(abi)
    const tokenFarmContract = new Contract(tokenFarmAddress, tokenFarmInterface)

    const erc20ABI = ERC20.abi
    const erc20Interface = new utils.Interface(erc20ABI)
    const erc20Contract = new Contract(tokenAddress, erc20Interface)
    // approve
    const { send: approveErc20Send, state: approveAndStakeErc20State } =
        useContractFunction(erc20Contract, "approve", {
            transactionName: "Approve ERC20 transfer",
        })

}
```

The error occurs on `useContractFunction`with `erc20Contract`:

[Vscode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLFm9.png)

This is the complete error message

```
Argument of type 'import("/home/cromewar/Solidity-Projects/full_defi_app/dev/front_end/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index").Contract' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/home/cromewar/Solidity-Projects/full_defi_app/dev/front_end/node_modules/@usedapp/core/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index").Contract'.
  Types of property '_runningEvents' are incompatible.
    Type '{ [eventTag: string]: RunningEvent; }' is not assignable to type '{ [eventTag: string]: RunningEvent; }'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
      'string' index signatures are incompatible.
        Type 'RunningEvent' is not assignable to type 'RunningEvent'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
          Types have separate declarations of a private property '_listeners'.  TS2345

    23 |     // approve
    24 |     const { send: approveErc20Send, state: approveAndStakeErc20State } =
  > 25 |         useContractFunction(erc20Contract, "approve", {
       |                             ^
    26 |             transactionName: "Approve ERC20 transfer",
    27 |         })
    28 |
```

```
Argument of type 'import("/home/cromewar/Solidity-Projects/full_defi_app/dev/front_end/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index").Contract' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/home/cromewar/Solidity-Projects/full_defi_app/dev/front_end/node_modules/@usedapp/core/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index").Contract'.
  Types of property '_runningEvents' are incompatible.
    Type '{ [eventTag: string]: RunningEvent; }' is not assignable to type '{ [eventTag: string]: RunningEvent; }'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
      'string' index signatures are incompatible.
        Type 'RunningEvent' is not assignable to type 'RunningEvent'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
          Types have separate declarations of a private property '_listeners'.  TS2345
```

It says the types are not compatible but they are actually the exact same, does anyone has a clue about what is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

Replace this:

```
import {Contract} from '@ethersproject/contracts'
```

For this:

```
import {Contract} from '@usedapp/core/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts'
```